# Error when deploying deep learning model with android studio

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am doing a simple app, classifing images.

I am applying a tensorflow lite model on to the android app using java and android studio.

1 - Building UI

2 - Selecting image from local storage

3 - Capturing image using camera

4 - Handling permissions

5 - Loading the TensorFlow tfflite model

6 - Making predictions to the bitmap

I do not understand why is the error and how to fix it.

Error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.erfdrts.imagerecognition/com.erfdrts.imagerecognition.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1001; index=1001`

`imagerecognition.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button select, capture, predict;
    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    TextView result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //permisson
        getPermission();

        String[] labels = new String[1001]; 
        int cnt = 0;

        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("label.txt")));
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                                                    while (line!=null){ //LINE 57
                labels[cnt] = line;
                cnt++;
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        select = findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect);
        predict = findViewById(R.id.buttonPredict);
        capture = findViewById(R.id.buttonPredict);
        result = findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        select.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
            }
        });

        capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 12);
            }
        });

        predict.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    MobilenetV110224Quant model = MobilenetV110224Quant.newInstance(MainActivity.this); 

                    // Creates inputs for reference.
                    TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 224, 224, 3}, DataType.FLOAT32);

                    
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 224, 224, true);
                    inputFeature0.loadBuffer(TensorImage.fromBitmap(bitmap).getBuffer());
                    MobilenetV110224Quant.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
                    TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();
                    result.setText(getMax(outputFeature0.getFloatArray()) +" "); 
        
                    model.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Handle the exception
                }
            }
        });

    }

    int getMax(float[] arr){
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if (arr[i] > arr[max]) max=i;
        }
        return max;
    }

    public void getPermission(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 11);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode==11){
            if (grantResults[0]!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                this.getPermission();
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==10){
            if (data!=null){
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
            }
        }
        else if(requestCode==12){ //the user have capture the image
            bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the indexes start from zero , since the the length of your array is 1001 and it wants to go to index of 1001, it means the computer is reaching for 1002th item and it crashes, so id throws java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
so you have to check why your loop or iterator is reaching out of your array length, maybe your logic is wrong ??